# pdf output from gnuplot is missing labels

Tags: texlive, gnuplot, epstopdf

When I run the following on my gnuplot script, the interactive Qt gnuplot window appears; the labelled graph I'm looking for appears as it should be; and I can select "export to pdf".

```
gnuplot -p -s -e "set terminal qt size 1800,1000" -c data100.gnuplot
```

I would like to get the same pdf, but without using the interactive Qt Gnuplot window. I have tried the following (and many variations):

```
gnuplot -p -s -e "set terminal postscript size 1800,1000; psoutfile='data100.ps'; set output psoutfile" -c data100.gnuplot
epstopdf data100.ps
```

But the graph in the pdf created here has no labels, or text at all (it is also oriented orthogonally). Can anyone suggest a remedy?

The contents of (a reduced version of) data100.gnuplot is:

```
set grid
set termoption dashed
set size 0.98 
set bmargin 10
set lmargin 18
set rmargin 8 
set xtics offset 0,-1,0
set xlabel offset 0,-3,0
set ytics offset -1,-1,0
set ylabel offset -8,0,0
set key font ",30"
set xtics font ",35"
set ytics font ",35"                                                            
set title "Test Graph" font ",35"                                               
set ylabel "Y-Axis Label" font ",35"                                            
set xlabel "X-Axis Label" font ",35"                                            
                                                                                
plot "data100.dat" every ::0::2 using 2:1 title 'V1' with linespoints dt 1 lw 3 ps 3, \
     "data100.dat" every ::3::5 using 2:1 title 'V2' with linespoints dt 2 lw 3 ps 3, \
     "data100.dat" every ::6::8 using 2:1 title 'V3' with linespoints dt 3 lw 3 ps 3
```

...and the data file it uses contains the following:

```
# V1
1.72358   4000       
6.948528 16000
27.66878 64000
# V2          
0.9029846 4000
3.669716 16000         
14.55772 64000          
# V3                    
0.5210688 4000          
2.07141  16000    
8.235494 64000
```

The PostScript output from the problematic second gnuplot command from above can be found at the PasteBin link [here](https://pastebin.com/EwTGgV1T).

Comment: Which TeX distribution you have installed, e.g. MiKTeX, TeX Live? Additionally, which fonts are supposed to be used within your .ps graphics - please check the .ps source code and identify all lines like these: `%%DocumentNeededResources: font Courier`, `%%IncludeResource: font Courier`, `/Courier findfont` and get back with more info.

Comment: I'm using TeX Live, installed as an APT package on Ubuntu 22.10. I don't know which fonts should be used: I searched for all files containing `DocumentNeededResources: font Courier` under `/usr`, but nothing was found.

Comment: **You should check the very .ps file you are working with, e.g. data100.ps.** Courier was the font in my file I checked, we need the font information from your file. Search all these: `%%DocumentNeededResources: font`, `%%IncludeResource: font`, `findfont`.

Comment: Ah, of course: the data100.ps file contains, no `DocumentNeededResources` nor `IncludeResource`, but quite a few instances of `/Helvetica findfont 140 scalefont setfont`.

Comment: It seems that `epstopdf` does not see any Helvetica variant installed in your system or TeX distribution, or it is completely missing. Can you share the output of `pdffonts your_pdf.pdf`?

Comment: Also, where does the `epstopdf` come from, e.g. please share the output of `which epstopdf` and `whereis epstopdf`?

Comment: The output from `pdffonts data100.pdf` is: `name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
PJMZXL+Helvetica                     Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no       7  0`. `epstopdf` comes from `texlive-font-utils: /usr/bin/epstopdf`.

Comment: From it everything looks ok. Are you able to share the .ps file somehow?

Comment: Any updates on this one?

Comment: I've added reduced versions of the gnuplot script, the data file, and the .ps file to the question. Thanks.

Comment: Do you think there is any hope @ivankokan ?